# How do I deploy two zend frame work based apps in apache2 like the one in tomcat

Tags: apache-2.2, tomcat, mod-rewrite, virtualhost, zend-framework

I have two Zend framework applications called `finance` and `fleet`. Both of them have the same .htaccess file as indicated below

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

I have created two virtual hosts called `fleet.local` and `finance.local`. This is my `fleet.local` file:

```
# APACHE CONFIGURATION FOR THE fleet.local APPLICATION    
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName fleet.local
    DocumentRoot /home/user/fleet/public 
    SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV dev 

    <Directory /home/user/fleet/public> 
        DirectoryIndex index.php
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

DeflateCompressionLevel 9
```

And this is my `finance.local` file:

```
# APACHE CONFIGURATION FOR THE fincance.local APPLICATION

<VirtualHost *:80>        
    ServerName fincance.local
    DocumentRoot /home/user/fincance/public 
    SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV dev 

    <Directory /home/user/fincance/public> 
        DirectoryIndex index.php
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

DeflateCompressionLevel 9
```

When I want to use finance I will say `http://finance.local` and when I want to use fleet I will say `http://fleet.local`.

Now what I want to do is have a single virtual host called `companyX.local` and if I want the finance application, I will just type `http://companyX.local/finance` and `http://companyX.local/fleet` for my fleet application. How do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it!!!

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerName companyX.local

    Alias /finance "/home/user/finance/public"

    <Directory /home/user/finance/public> 
        DirectoryIndex index.php
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    Alias /fleet "/home/user/fleet/public"

    <Directory /home/user/fleet/public>
        DirectoryIndex index.php
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

and changed the rewrite base for finance like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /finance
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

and changed the rewrite base for fleet like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /fleet
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

Try this — it doesn't even need RewriteBase and will work root relative or in a subdir.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)(.+)::\2$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [E=BASE:%1]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{ENV:BASE}index.php [NC,L]
```